# How to get name of song instead od title in xml file using getItemInfo() in c#

Tags: c#, media-player

I am creating an xml file for my all my songs in my songs folder from c#.net.My code is as follows:

```
 Microsoft.MediaPlayer.Interop.IWMPMedia mediafilesinformation = plist.get_Item(i);
                   mediafilesinformation = obj_wmp.newMedia(filepath);
                    Filename = mediafilesinformation.getItemInfo("SourceURL");
                    Tracknumber = mediafilesinformation.getItemInfo("WM/TrackNumber");
                    Genre = mediafilesinformation.getItemInfo("WM/Genre");
                    Album = mediafilesinformation.getItemInfo("WM/AlbumTitle");
                    Artist = mediafilesinformation.getItemInfo("Artist");
                    Name = mediafilesinformation.getItemInfo("Name");
                    Duration = double.Parse(mediafilesinformation.getItemInfo("Duration"));
```

I am getting the title of the song in Name,but i have to get the Name of the song.Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: Did you check the file properties ? May be the Name attribute has Title in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Name attribute in the properties points to FileName if you need that you then you you can use your filepath string.

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
```

You can also print out all the attributes, debug them and see what values are being held by the attributes. Use [Media.getAttributeName method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563844%28VS.85%29.aspx). An example from the same link is below:

```
// Store the current media object.
var cm = Player.currentMedia;

// Get the number of attributes for the current media. 
var atCount = cm.attributeCount;

// Loop through the attribute list.
for(var i=0; i < atCount; i++){

   // Print each attribute index and name.   
   myText.value += "Attribute " + i +": ";
   myText.value += cm.getAttributeName(i);
   myText.value += "\n";
}
```

Comment: I want the song name but not song's title. I used both Title and Name as                                                                 name= mediafilesinformation.getItemInfo("Name");                            Title= mediafilesinformation.getItemInfo("Title");                        ,but I am getting only the title but not Name of the song.

Comment: @srivani, what do you mean by song name ? I think when you do getItemInfo("Name") it will give you the name, do you want the file name ?

Comment: When we open properties of song,we will have title and also Name.I want that Name of the song.Even I used name ,I am getting the title of thyat song only.

Comment: @srivani, In file properties under details Name attribute points to Name of the file e.g. somesong.mp3, you want that? I couldn't find a different Name attribute under media property

Comment: @srivani, you have filepath variable, you can use that to get the filename. I have edited the answer see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Follow these Reference links and code snippet.. Hope this help

Ref: [Getting duration for audio or video clip without actually playing the clip](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.windowsmedia.sdk/browse_thread/thread/888aa90cf4bdd23d/627924eacd07cab1)

```
Microsoft.MediaPlayer.Interop.IWMPMedia m = Player.newMedia(fileName);

string currentArtist = m.getItemInfo("Author").Trim();
string currentAlbum = m.getItemInfo("Album").Trim();
string currentTitle = m.getItemInfo("Title").Trim();
double duration = m.duration;
```

Ref: [Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/451466.aspx/1)

```
Microsoft.MediaPlayer.Interop.IWMPPlaylist plist; 
plist = x.mediaCollection.getAll();                        

for(int i=0; i < plist.count;i++) 
{ 
        Microsoft.MediaPlayer.Interop.IWMPMedia elem = plist.get_Item(i); 

        Response.Write(string.Format("{1} - {2} - {3} - {4} - {5}
", 
                elem.sourceURL, 
                elem.name, 
                elem.getItemInfo("MediaType"), 
                elem.getItemInfo("FileType"), 
                elem.getItemInfo("WM/TrackNumber"), 
                elem.getItemInfo("Author"), 
                elem.getItemInfo("Title") 
        )); 
}
```